# ConfiguredJsonCodec for snake case ADT

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have to consume a json api, where there is a list of discrete string values in snake case.

The example below works, but I would like to remove the manual `fooDecoder` in favor of the (currently commented out) ConfiguredJsonCodec annotation.

Or more fundamental question: Does modeling these discrete values as case objects in an ADT even makes sense, or is there another approach?

```scala
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.extras.{Configuration, ConfiguredJsonCodec, JsonKey}
import io.circe.parser.parse

implicit val jsonConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default
  .withSnakeCaseConstructorNames
  .withSnakeCaseMemberNames

//@ConfiguredJsonCodec(decodeOnly = true)
sealed trait Foo
object Foo {
  case object FooBar extends Foo
  case object FooBaz extends Foo
  case object FooWuz extends Foo
}

import Foo._
implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[Foo] = new Decoder[Foo] {
  override def apply(c: HCursor) = c.as[String].map{
    case "foo_bar" => FooBar
    case "foo_baz" => FooBaz
    case "foo_wuz" => FooWuz
  }
}

@ConfiguredJsonCodec(decodeOnly = true)
case class Qux(fooFoo: List[Foo])

val input ="""{"foo_foo" : ["foo_bar", "foo_baz", "foo_wuz"]}"""
val json: Json = parse(input).left.map(println(_)).right.get

json.as[Qux]
```

Complete example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eVFyNMGFRgaw9oEkRveT8g

This uses circe 0.13.0

Answer (score 2):

All Circe derivation methods for coproducts assume that there is discrimination field and at best you can pick its name. So the supported format is something like:

```
{
  "type": "foo_bar",
}
```

instead of just

```
"foo_bar"
```

The reason is that derivation mechanism sees no difference between case-object-only and case-object-and-case-classes, so for code like this

```
trait MyADT
object MyADT {
  case class Value1(value: String) extends MyADT
  case class Value2(value: String) extends MyADT
}
```

where you simply would combine codecs of sum's parts

```
val decoder: Decoder[MyADT] = Decoder[Value1].widen orElse Decoder[Value2].widen
```

you would always decode to first `Value1` even if you encoded `Value2`. Derivation sees no difference between these two cases and so they prefer to be on the safe side always by using discrimination field. (This is [discussed in docs](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html)).

However, if you know that you are building enum, you can simply use enumeratum with circe support:

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait Foo extends EnumEntry with Snakecase
object Foo extends Enum[Foo] with CirceEnum[Foo] {
  case object FooBar extends Foo
  case object FooBaz extends Foo
  case object FooWuz extends Foo

  val values = findValues
}
```

This would achieve the very goal you aim for, although in a different way.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately i have no influence on the json format I consume. I'll consider using enumeratum though.